# How does the target definition work?

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't wrap my head around the eclipse target definition.

From the wiki:
[The Target Platform is a critical part of developing using PDE. It defines what your workspace will be built and launched against.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/Target_Definitions)

When building a Java application I understand that the CLASSPATH has to contain all the imported packages. Is this related to the `.target` file? Someone told me that the `.target` file is like a CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PDE, I'm guessing that you are developing a **plugin** for Eclipse.

Any plugin depends on classes in the **Eclipse platform**. The Target Platform defines the exact version of the Eclipse platform you develop for.

Technically, it is a list of bundles (~jar files) in your class path, that come as parts of the platform (and therefore will be present in the user's installation even when you don't ship them), i.e. jars that handle workspace file management, startup, file editing etc.

Comment: So the target is like a glorified CLASSPATH?

Comment: Class path is an ordered collection of JAR files your code compiles against. Part of it comes from the target platform, otehr parts come from configuration parameters of your projects (i.e. by what your MANIFEST.MF might say).

Answer (score 0):

Target platform and CLASSPATH are not one and the same. The CLASSPATH variable is used to tell your applications where to look for user classes.

Whereas a target platform refers to the set of plug-ins which your workspace will be built and run against.This eclipse documentation link [TargetPlatform](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm) should help you understand how the target definition works. Also look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) on how to define a target platform.

Comment: I followed your links but they don't add more than what you said. When you say that my workspace will be buit against the target plug-ins does that mean that the CLASSPATH will contain all packages in the target plug-ins?